# postgresql dynamic function

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic

I am replacing hard-coded names by parameters and need to create a dynamic sql string.  Bur whatever I do, I do not suceed in replacing 'param', 'schema' and 'tablename_2' in my subquery.  Next is my function as it is working partly and thereafter is my errror message.  I assume it is just a question of inserting the proper quotes at the proper location.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function_112(schema text, tablename_1 text, tablename_2 text, param integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(schema) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename_1) ||'
                        ("gid", "osm_id", "name", "geom", "line_type")
                        SELECT ("gid", "osm_id", "name", ST_SetSRID("geom", 4326), param)
                        FROM ''|| quote_ident(schema) || ''.'' || quote_ident(tablename_2) ||'';'
                    RETURN;
                END
 $function$
```

--> leading to error message :

```
QUERY:  INSERT INTO public."National_Grid_multiline"
                        ("gid", "osm_id", "name", "geom", "line_type")
                        SELECT ("gid", "osm_id", "name", ST_SetSRID("geom", 4326), param)
                        FROM '|| quote_ident(schema) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename_2) ||';
```

Comment: Lose the `''` for the section after `FROM`. So: `FROM '|| quote_ident(schema) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename_2) ||';'` .Life would be easier if you followed the `format` examples from [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: already tried that without any luck

Comment: Furthermore, it does not influence the 'param' parameter either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here is the proper solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.afri_terra_112(schema text, tablename_1 text, tablename_2 text, param integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(schema) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename_1) ||
                        ' ("gid", "osm_id", "name", "geom", "line_type") '
                        ' SELECT "gid", "osm_id", "name", ST_SetSRID("geom", 4326), '|| param ||' '
                        ' FROM ' || quote_ident(schema) || '."'|| quote_ident(tablename_2) ||'"';
                    RETURN;
                END
 $function$
```